# Time serie group by week python

Tags: python, pandas

I would like to aggregate this table by week in python:

```
    Date       x    y    z
   01/01/2016   0   0   1015
   02/01/2016   0   0   1015
   03/01/2016   0   0   1015
   04/01/2016   5   0   1020
   05/01/2016   6   1   1016
   06/01/2016   9   3   1020
   07/01/2016   4   0   1025
   08/01/2016   2   5   1008
```

Thanks.

Comment: What kind of aggregation? Can you explain more?

Comment: sum for example.

Answer (score 3):

First convert column to datetime by [`to_datetime`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.to_datetime.html) and then aggregate by `sum` with [`weekofyear`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.Series.dt.weekofyear.html):

```
df['Date'] = pd.to_datetime(df['Date'], format='%d/%m/%Y')
print (df)
        Date  x  y     z
0 2016-01-01  0  0  1015
1 2016-01-02  0  0  1015
2 2016-01-03  0  0  1015
3 2016-01-04  5  0  1020
4 2016-01-05  6  1  1016
5 2016-01-06  9  3  1020
6 2016-01-07  4  0  1025
7 2016-01-08  2  5  1008

df1 = df.groupby(df['Date'].dt.weekofyear).sum()
print (df1)
       x  y     z
Date             
1     26  9  5089
53     0  0  3045
```

Or [`dayofweek`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.Series.dt.dayofweek.html):

```
df2 = df.groupby(df['Date'].dt.dayofweek).sum()
print (df2)
      x  y     z
Date            
0     5  0  1020
1     6  1  1016
2     9  3  1020
3     4  0  1025
4     2  5  2023
5     0  0  1015
6     0  0  1015
```